# How to return to previous block of code in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on code for this magic 8ball game. I cant seem to find a way to return to getAnswer() when the user types "y" in replay. how do I fix this?

```
import random
import time
import sys

print('  __  __          _____ _____ _____    ___  ')
print(' |  \/  |   /\   / ____|_   _/ ____|  / _ \ ')
print(' | \  / |  /  \ | |  __  | || |      | (_) |')
print(' | |\/| | / /\ \| | |_ | | || |       > _ < ')
print(' | |  | |/ ____ \ |__| |_| || |____  | (_) |')
print(' |_|  |_/_/    \_\_____|_____\_____|  \___/ ')
print('')
print('')
print('')
print('Hello, I am the magic 8ball program... What is your name?') 
name = input()
print('')
print('Hello, ' + name + '...')

def getAnswer(answerNumber):
    print('ask me a question')
    input()
    print('predicting...')
    time.sleep(2)
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'It is certain' 
    elif answerNumber == 2: 
        return 'It is decidingly so' 
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes' 
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return 'reply hazy, try again' 
    elif answerNumber == 5: 
        return 'no' 
    elif answerNumber == 6: 
        return 'ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 7: 
        return 'concentrate and ask again' 
    elif answerNumber == 8: 
        return 'Outlook does not look good' 
    elif answerNumber == 9: 
        return 'I highly doubt so' 
print(getAnswer(random.randint(1,9)))

def replay():
    print('do you have another question? [y/n]')
    reply = input()
    if reply == 'y' or 'Y' or 'Yes' or 'yes':
        getAnswer()
    elif reply == 'n' or 'N' or 'No' or 'no':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('My apologies, I did not catch that. Please try again.')
        replay()

replay()
```

I placed getAnswer() under "if reply" hoping it would revert back to the first variable in the beginning of the code. the program errors stating that it is missing one positional requirement yet when I place answerNumber in getAnswer() its just another error.

I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
import random
import time
import sys

print('  __  __          _____ _____ _____    ___  ')
print(' |  \/  |   /\   / ____|_   _/ ____|  / _ \ ')
print(' | \  / |  /  \ | |  __  | || |      | (_) |')
print(' | |\/| | / /\ \| | |_ | | || |       > _ < ')
print(' | |  | |/ ____ \ |__| |_| || |____  | (_) |')
print(' |_|  |_/_/    \_\_____|_____\_____|  \___/ ')
print('')
print('')
print('')
print('Hello, I am the magic 8ball program... What is your name?') 
name = input()
print('')
print('Hello, ' + name + '...')

def getAnswer(answerNumber):
    print('ask me a question')
    input()
    print('predicting...')
    time.sleep(2)
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'It is certain' 
    elif answerNumber == 2: 
        return 'It is decidingly so' 
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes' 
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return 'reply hazy, try again' 
    elif answerNumber == 5: 
        return 'no' 
    elif answerNumber == 6: 
        return 'ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 7: 
        return 'concentrate and ask again' 
    elif answerNumber == 8: 
        return 'Outlook does not look good' 
    elif answerNumber == 9: 
        return 'I highly doubt so' 
print(getAnswer(random.randint(1,9)))

def replay():
    while True: #keep replaying 
        print('do you have another question? [y/n]')
        reply = input()
        if reply == 'y' or 'Y' or 'Yes' or 'yes':
            getAnswer(random.randint(1,9)) #choose random answer
        elif reply == 'n' or 'N' or 'No' or 'no':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print('My apologies, I did not catch that. Please try again.')
            replay()

replay()
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I ran the revision in my code and the code suddenly ends in line 22 where it says print('predicting").